# Using "Raspberry Pi" in titles (and questions)

Tags: discussion, formatting

While it is not as much of a concern in the questions itself, it seems like it may be important to avoid putting "Raspberry Pi" in the title of questions due to repetition and congestion.  How can this be avoided?

Comment: I believe that there are several blocked words (like "help"). Couldn't we add "Raspberry Pi" (and its derivatives) to that list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would drop it altogether in titles. We can folow the precedent from Stack Overflow of not mentioning programming languages in titles unless necessary (there are usually tags for that).

Comment: I think marking this as an answer might be a bit premature. I suggest waiting until the community is more than an hour old at least :-P

Comment: I agree. This is just my opinion.

Comment: If the device name is necessary in the title, I suggest we stick to "Raspberry Pi" for formality, rather than abbreviating.

Comment: The programming languages vs. tags thing on Stack Overflow has gotten out of hand.  It hurts readability, hurts SEO (the vast majority of people get to SE sites from Google) and titles are titles for a reason - tags and titles are segregated in the interface with tags de-emphasised.

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that any form of "Raspberry Pi" on a site entirely dedicated to Raspberry Pi is a bit redundant. However on the occaisions where it aids clarity, then a sensible acronym or contraction seems appropriate. I've seen "RPi" used a bit already and it seems like a good compromise to me.

Comment: This is the "official" shorthand version of Raspberry Pi, although I can't find the page on the site which mentions it.

Comment: I suspect that it will be far more constructive to keep to one standard abbreviation (i.e. this one), than to try to ban them completely.

Answer (score 7):

Re: this question;
[Is it safe to operate on any dry surface?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135/is-it-safe-to-operate-a-rasp-pi-on-any-dry-surface)

I would think it'd be much more useful in terms of SEO to include the term 'a rasp pi' in the title rather than something along the lines of 'the device'. If anything the better change may be to extend the abbreviation to include the full 'raspberry' word.

Comment: Happy to change question title if someone can suggest a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If an object or subject is required, and it does not hurt the clarity of the title or question, it may be better to say "the device."  The words "Raspberry Pi" should only appear in the title of a question where absolutely necessary for clarity.

It's important, especially early on, that the community makes sure to edit question titles to set a precedent for this practice.

Comment: I would drop it altogether in titles. We can folow the precedent from Stack Overflow of not mentioning programming languages in titles unless necessary (there are usually tags for that).

Comment: You should add this as an answer.

Comment: "The device" seems a bit clunky. RasPi? RP? Pi?

Comment: That still has the problem of being repetitive.  I think @Tibor's answer is a good one.

Comment: Will Search engines associate these Titles with Raspberry Pi? Are there meta tags or something to link all this together?

Answer (score 1):

So I was just searching for something related after asking how seach engines ascociate titles and results..

Maybe the name in the domain is good enough.. and then it scans for matches within indexed titles. It is obvios here it matched

`raspberrypi` in the `domain` name and then also in the `titles`.. So the results are useless because `directfb` is last because `raspberry` was matched first based on the search text.

So should be make a definitive answer and rule that Raspberry Pi should be avoided as much as possible in titles. As the above answer was accepted.. but not confirmed in the community.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that so far, there ARE a few questions where it makes sense to have `Raspberry Pi` in the title. (Ref: [Where can I buy a Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/112/90)) but it does seem like it could get crowded quick without proper moderation. And I know the true "algorithm" to SEO is a mystery, but too much could seem like keyword flooding to an elementary crawler and potentially hurt the overall SEO of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with the others, it would be out of place to be discussing Windows or Beaglebone for example and so the fact the question is about the Raspberry Pi should be taken for granted.