# Are we replacing RPi by "a unit" or "the device"?

Tags: discussion

Several references to the RPi in titles have been replaced by "a unit" or "the device", as per [Using “Raspberry Pi” in titles (and questions)](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/using-raspberry-pi-in-titles-and-questions). Is this right? Was it the intention?

#### Examples

- [Can these devices be used within commercial products?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/208/can-these-devices-be-used-within-commercial-products)
- [Is it possible to receive an electric shock by touching a unit while it's on?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/167/is-it-possible-to-receive-an-electric-shock-by-touching-a-unit-while-its-on)
- [Is it possible to set up a unit as a wireless router?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/243/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-unit-as-a-wireless-router)

Answer (score 17):

Are these overly pedantic micro-edit policies getting out of hand?

I really **do** appreciate the tremendous efforts to get this site ready for opening day. This is going to be a *fantastic* site with a first-rate community — But there's also a point where these efforts turn into rules just *looking* for a problem. What you'll end up with is a foreboding community with a faq that looks like the bulleted list from hell.

So regarding *"Are we replacing all…"*

You have to be really careful with these *sweeping* binary policy decisions. Your main source of traffic into this site is Google search. You're going to turn this site from one about "Raspberry Pi" to one about **"the device & unit."** These misguided efforts to enforce some sense of "verboten redundancy" will only make your content look stilted and unnatural… and **un-findable.**

Relax and write what feels natural to you. Clarity is paramount in titles. If the question *feels* well-written if posed in the form

> *"How do I reboot my RaspPi?"*

… then write that. But please don't assemble an enforcer squad to change all such occurrences to

> *"How do I reboot the aforementioned device?"*

Take a look at the title lists in these sites:

[Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/?tab=active)

[SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/?tab=active)

It all flows very naturally. Most of the questions provide plenty of context — all without codifying an *all-or-nothing* policy.

Edit the question if it can be improved. But think about the context of what you are doing. Saying, *"Is it possible to receive an electric shock by touching a unit while it's on?"* is simply a horrible title, as are the other "improvements."

Comment: Good answer.  The google / 'searchability' point is especially important.

Comment: +1 Agreed. We want answers given here to be quickly available to the public.

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad this has come up - I've seen a few suggested edits I've rejected that actually made the title more ambiguous or less readable by removing the "RPi" reference (in whatever abbreviation / form.)

While I agree with removing it from the title where the question can be represented in the same way in a more succinct form, please don't blindly remove it if there's not a better way of putting it (or it's just a case of substituting it with "the device".) That's not the point!

Answer (score 3):

## No

It was the intention of the other question to minimise its use. In these cases, its use is justified.