# How are we going to deal with the naming convention?

Tags: discussion

So far I came accros RPi, raspberry, rasberrypi, Raspberry PI ; all of which are non trademarked as the original **Raspberry Pi**

Do we just go and fix all those mentioned in the latter to the official name as specific in in the [Raspberry Pi's trademark rules?](http://www.raspberrypi.org/trademark-rules)

Answer (score 3):

We have been trying to encourage users to not use shorthand and to just type **Raspberry Pi**.

However, it's probably unlikely that we will be able to eradicate all shorthand, and editing every occurrence of Raspberry Pi slang would take continual effort, it's probably best not to worry about it that much.

If you see something that irritates you then feel free to edit, though it's usually discouraged to edit posts simply for spelling corrections, unless they detract from the meaning. But I will do it myself on occasion, for example, RaspPi thoroughly annoys my eyes.

Either way, don't let it keep you up at night.

Also, somewhat relevant, unless absolutely necessary, avoid from using Raspberry Pi references in titles. Discussion about this is [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/using-raspberry-pi-in-titles-and-questions).